# Cross-origin cookie error working with Express and React

Tags: docker, express, cookies, cross-domain

I am deploying a repo that has frontend and backend. The server runs Express and is in charge of serving the files that have been generated from the frontend build.

```
this.application = express();
        this.application.use(function(req, res, next) {
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin); //solve error
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, Accept, Set-Cookie'); //solve error
            if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
                 res.sendStatus(200);
             } else {
                 next();
             }
        });
        this.application.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));
        this.application.use(compression());
        this.application.use(bodyParser.raw());
        this.application.use(bodyParser.text());
        this.application.use(cookieParser());
        this.application.use(bodyParser.json());
        this.application.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

        this.application.use(express.static('../front/build'));
        this.registerControllers();
        this.configureGraphQL();
        this.application.get('*', (req, res) => {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../../../front/build', 'index.html'));
        });
```

I deploy with docker, so when I start the container everything runs on port 80 (HTTP).

```
FROM node:18

WORKDIR /app/front

COPY front/package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY front/ .

RUN npm run build

WORKDIR /app/back

COPY back/package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY back/ .

RUN npm run build   

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["node", "build/index.j
```

Everything works fine, the frontend views are loaded correctly, you can make correct calls to the backend endpoints, but in the user login, when I try to save a cookie generated with jwt from the backend, I get the following error:
Auth endpoint funcion:

```
UserAuthController.userAuthService.login(email, password).then((token) => {
            res.cookie('auth-token', token, {httpOnly: true, secure: false}); //solve error
            //res.cookie('auth-token', token, {secure: true, sameSite: 'none'});
            res.status(STATUS_OK);
            res.contentType(CONTENT_APPLICATION_JSON);
            res.json({"code": STATUS_OK, "message": "Login successful"});
            return;
        }).catch((err) => {
            res.status(STATUS_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            res.contentType(CONTENT_APPLICATION_JSON);
            res.json({"code": STATUS_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "message": err});
            return;
        });
```

Response:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1g5d.png)
I understand that up to this point the backend has correctly requested to save the cookie.
But this appear in the browser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zo7S.png)

I have been trying to solve this problem for several days now but I don't understand what is wrong. If the back and front end are running on the same domain and same port, it should not be a cross-origin response.
Can you help me?

At first I had it on different ports, I changed it so that the backend in express would serve the files from the frontend, but it still doesn't work and still gives cross-origin.